# create an intermediate step to verify the email address using firebase, react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to verify my email address using react native and firebase. Currently, I have a signup page, after putting in all the credentials, it sends a verification link to the email, and I am getting directly to a new screen. There is no way to verify my email. First, I am trying to verify my email, By clicking the email link, then, I can navigate to the new screen. I am trying to create an intermediate step to verify my email address, at the moment there is no way to verify my email link.

Here is my try,

```
register: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            const userCredential = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email,
              password,
          );
         await userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();
       } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
},
```

and here is my try to redirecting to a new screen.

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import {AuthContext} from './AuthProvider';

import AuthStack from './AuthStack';
import AppStack from './AppStack';

const Routes = () => {
    // getting the created user
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
 
  // subscribe to the users current authentication state, and receive an event whenever that state changes.
  const onAuthStateChanged = user => {
    setUser(user);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);


  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#create_the_email_action_handler_page?

Answer (score 1):

You could set set the user only if the email is verified as shown below. And add an intermediate screen if the user email address is not verified.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(false);
const [emailVerified, setEmailVerified] = useState(true);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        if(user.emailVerified){
            setUser(true);  setEmailVerified(true);

        }
        else{
            setEmailVerified(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Then use your conditional render like this:

```
{user && <AppStack />}
{!user && <AuthStack />}
{!emailVerified && <EmailPendingVerifiedScreen />}
```